# Use sf (R) to return the overlapping area between two polygons by rows?

Tags: r, overlapping-features, sf

I have two sfc data frames with the same number of rows (individual IDs), but each data frame contains a polygon assigned to the individual. For example, dataframe1 may have a circle assigned neared an individuals' home coordinate, while dataframe2 has a square assigned near their home coordinate.

In some cases, the square and circle overlap for an individual. In some cases, they do not. I want to know, when they *do* overlap, what is the area of that overlapping space.

At present I've been using `st_intersection`, but this, of course, returns the area overlapped by *all* circles (y)  for an individual's square (x). I've considered a loop as well, but it seems that `st_intersection` won't work in cases where x and y do not overlap.

Perhaps a loop with a skip-error function built in? Or a more simpler way...?

Comment: " I've considered a loop as well, but it seems that st_intersection won't work in cases where x and y do not overlap." how does it not work? It returns an empty geometry. If your code isn't handling that then that's a problem with your code. You are probably very close to a solution with your loop - if you include your code then we might be able to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make two sf data frames of circles from two sets of 10 points in a unit square:

```
 set.seed(123)
 p1 = st_cast(st_sfc(st_multipoint(cbind(runif(10),runif(10)))),"POINT")
 p2 = st_cast(st_sfc(st_multipoint(cbind(runif(10),runif(10)))),"POINT")
 b1 =st_buffer(p1, .15)
 b2 =st_buffer(p2, .15)
 b1d = data.frame(id=1:10)
 b1d$geometry = b1
 b1d = st_as_sf(b1d)
 b2d = data.frame(id=1:10)
 b2d$geometry = b2
 b2d = st_as_sf(b2d)
```

Now compute the intersections by row:

```
s12 = lapply(1:nrow(b1d), function(i){st_intersection(b1d[i,],b2d[i,])})
```

ignore the warning messages.

The return list has empty elements if no overlap, geometry elements if there is an overlap:

```
> s12[[1]]
Simple feature collection with 0 features and 2 fields
bbox:           xmin: NA ymin: NA xmax: NA ymax: NA
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
[1] id       id.1     geometry
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> s12[[3]]
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0.4905068 ymin: 0.5891645 xmax: 0.5589769 ymax: 0.7791115
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
  id id.1                       geometry
3  3    3 POLYGON ((0.5589769 0.67757...
```

And if you row-bind them all together you get rid of the empty ones:

```
> do.call(rbind, s12)
Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0.401435 ymin: 0.03859731 xmax: 1.013404 ymax: 0.7791115
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
  id id.1                       geometry
3  3    3 POLYGON ((0.5589769 0.67757...
4  4    4 POLYGON ((0.8638831 0.72135...
5  5    5 POLYGON ((0.8050175 0.03859...
9  9    9 POLYGON ((0.423012 0.250504...
```

showing you that rows 3,4,5 and 9 in `b1d` overlap the corresponding rows in `b2d`. Plotting this object will show you the intersection areas.